# Scrapy: Modifying elements and fields in a response

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy, lxml

I'm relatively new to Scrapy, Python and object-oriented programming so apologies if I get any terminology incorrect or am unclear in any way.

I'm trying to write a spider that, as it scrapes items from a response, will also create a modified version of the response to save to file. For example, I'm trying to alter 'src' links to point to scraped files saved locally.

Currently, I'm scraping data using Scrapy's selectors and modifying the response using lxml. However, I want to use Scrapy's methods to do the modifications instead of lxml as using both Scrapy selectors and lxml means essentially doubling code to locate the same elements in a response.

I've added some code below to illustrate my point. Everything occurs in the spider parse function.

def parse(self, response):

```
    # Scrape thumbnail URLs using Scrapy selectors
    for post in response.css('.post'): # For each post
        for thumb in post.css('.thumb'): # For each thumbnail
            item = Item() # Create an image item
            item['thumbnail_url'] = []
            item['thumbnail_savepath'] = []
            for x in thumb.xpath('img/@src').extract():
                thumbnail_url = 'https:' + x
                thumbnail_filename = re.search('.*/(.*)', thumbnail_url).group(1)
                thumbnail_savepath = 'thumbnails/' + thumbnail_filename
                item['thumbnail_url'] += [thumbnail_url]
                item['thumbnail_savepath'] += [thumbnail_savepath]

    # Make modified html using lxml
    body_lxml = lxml.html.document_fromstring(response.body)
    for thumbnail in body_lxml.xpath('//img'):
        thumbnail_src = thumbnail.get('src') # Original link address
        thumbnail_path = './thumbnails/' + basename(thumbnail_src) # New link address
        thumbnail.set('src',image_path) # Setting new link address
```

As the code shows, it iterates through the images to scrape the items using Scrapy selectors, then iterates a second time using lxml for modifying the response. I have to use two different methods to loop over the same elements, which I'm trying to avoid. I'd like to do the scraping and modification in the same for loop if possible.

I was thinking it was possible to use the response.request() method but am struggling to understand how to use this from the documentation and searches online. Is there some method that allows Scrapy to modify individual elements or fields in a response? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please read the documentation of [scrapy pipelines](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#item-pipeline) and try to be more specific with your question. See [ask]

Comment: Hi Frank. Thanks for taking notice of my question. I've added some sample code and tried to make the question more specific and clear. Everything occurs in the main spider parse function (i.e. before the pipelines). Let me know if I can still make the question clearer for you/others. Marcus

Comment: @FrankMartin I feel that this is an example of a question that follows all the guidelines listed on that page. It is clear, specific, correctly tagged, well written in terms of grammar and word choice, and from a first-time user.

Comment: @Borealid IMHO the initial question (see version before edit) is not clear and specific. But I didn't downvote/ignore it, but gave advice how to improve the question (wich it did by editing). My comment was not meant to be rude in any way but encouraging. Sorry for not being clear on that.

Answer (score 1):

> Currently, I'm scraping data using Scrapy's selectors and modifying the response using lxml. However, I want to use Scrapy's methods to do the modifications instead of lxml as using both Scrapy selectors and lxml means essentially doubling code to locate the same elements in a response.

[Parsel](http://parsel.readthedocs.io/) Selectors (which Scrapy uses underneath) are designed to extract information, not to edit the underlying HTML. I believe your current approach is the best possible approach.

If you really want to avoid the sense of duplication you could use lxml only, but I strongly suggest you don’t do that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused as well as what you're trying to achieve, you're trying to modify from the selectors correct?

I know it goes against overflow policy to inquire more in a response but truly some stuff needs to weekly up

Looking at  just the code it seems like you're trying to do concatenate to edit your items.

What is the generator that is being referred to two then " edit"  what is the final output correct?   If this is so then what's happening is that you cannot concatenate implicitly list and strings.

[image]

what you have to do in this case is to strip then you join and set the value  for each...  If you or anyone has something similar please provide full examples of  any code that might be relevant... Like in this case would be the entire spider code...And pipeline even though the original poster is not using one as he should if he expects to save or I could always just use write function